# stable sorting using python bubble sort

Tags: python, sorting

So, I got my list of tuples to sort out by order of ints. What I'm missing is making the sort stable..

How can i make bubble sort stable? (keep order on similar items)

```
def bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list):
    NEWLIST = []
    ITEM_MOVE = 0
    for i in tuples_list:
        NEWLIST.append(i)
    for i in range(len(NEWLIST)):
         for j in range(i+1, len(NEWLIST)):
             if(NEWLIST[j][1] < NEWLIST[i][1]):
                 ITEM_MOVE = 1
                 NEWLIST[j],NEWLIST[i] = NEWLIST[i],NEWLIST[j]

    if (ITEM_MOVE == 0):
        print(tuples_list)
    else:
        print(NEWLIST)

tuples_list =  [('h2', 8), ('h4', 30), ('h6', 7), ('h8', 54), ('h1', 72), ('h3', 8), ('h5', 7), ('h7', 15), ('h7', 24)]

bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list)
```

tester resault which is expected and y resault comparison :
Showing output from element 0
expected: [('h6', 7), ('h5', 7), ('h2', 8), ('h3', 8), ('h7', 15), ('h9', 24), ('h4', 30), ('h8', 54), ('h1', 72)]
actual:   [('h6', 7), ('h5', 7), ('h3', 8), ('h2', 8), ('h7', 15), ('h9', 24), ('h4', 30), ('h8', 54), ('h1', 72)]
result_code     bubble_14       wrong   1

notice the h2/3 mix... need to fix it.. that what i mean by not stable

Comment: Variable names in ALL CAPS, random tab characters in the middle of lines, using `0` and `1` to mean `False` and `True`, unnecessary parens, etc.… all of this makes it much harder to read, and therefore debug, your code.

Comment: Meanwhile, this isn't a bubble sort. The whole point of bubble sort is that each time through, you compare each element only to its immediate neighbor. The reason you keep an `ITEM_MOVE` flag is that you need to keep looping until it's false. So, there's no way to turn this into a stable bubble sort is to throw it out and write a bubble sort in the first place (which will automatically be stable).

Comment: @abarnet I'm pretty sure his current code is bubble sort. `ITEM_MOVE` does nothing more but short-circuit the print logic, which arguably is unnecessary.

Comment: @Manny D - no, it's not a Bubble Sort.  It's a Selection Sort with a whole bunch of unnecessary swapping.

Comment: @user2970357 - heed abarnert's advice here.  Bubble sorts are inherently sort stable.  All you would need to do is implement the algorithm correctly - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: followed your advice and edited my code to match the algorithm. works! thanks and thanks for everyone who helped me with this!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do right now is to understand why it is switching those items. Print at every step what items are being changed. Then you might understand the behaviour.

So I had a go at it, you don't compare the current item with the next item in the list, you compare the current item with all the following items in the list. The changes I made bellow might give you the result you want.

```
def bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list):
    NEWLIST = []
    ITEM_MOVE = 0
    for i in tuples_list:
        NEWLIST.append(i)
    for i in range(len(NEWLIST)):
         for j in range(len(NEWLIST)-1):
             k=j+1
             if(NEWLIST[j][1] > NEWLIST[k][1]):
                 ITEM_MOVE = 1
                 NEWLIST[j],NEWLIST[k] = NEWLIST[k],NEWLIST[j]

    if (ITEM_MOVE == 0):
        print(tuples_list)
    else:
        print(NEWLIST)

tuples_list =  [('h2', 8), ('h4', 30), ('h6', 7), ('h8', 54), ('h1', 72), ('h3', 8), ('h5', 7), ('h7', 15), ('h7', 24)]

bubble_sort_2nd_value(tuples_list)
```

So what you are doing is not 100% bubble sort. Try this and tell me if you need me to explain why yours is not working.

Comment: for input of tuples_list =  [('a', 2), ('b',2), ('c', 1)] your code returns [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)].   the correct output should be [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2)]

Comment: I tried it a couple of times and it runs fine. Are you sure you are using (NEWLIST[j][1] > NEWLIST[k][1]) and not (NEWLIST[j][1] < NEWLIST[k][1]) ? It works fine for me. Tested at http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php